# Java Temporary File Multithreaded Application

Tags: java

I'm looking for a foolproof way to generate a temporary file that will have always end up with a unique name on a per JVM basis. Basically I want to be sure in a multithreaded application that if two or more threads attempt to create a temporary file at the exact same moment in time that they will both end up with a unique temporary file and no exceptions will be thrown.

This is the method I have currently:

```
public File createTempFile(InputStream inputStream) throws FileUtilsException {
    File tempFile = null;
    OutputStream outputStream = null;
    try {
        tempFile = File.createTempFile("app", ".tmp");
        tempFile.deleteOnExit();
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
        IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.debug("Unable to create temp file", e);
        throw new FileUtilsException(e);
    } finally {
        try { if (outputStream != null) outputStream.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
        try { if (inputStream != null) inputStream.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
    return tempFile;
}
```

Is this perfectly safe for what my goal is? I reviewed the documentation at the below URL but I'm not sure.

See [java.io.File#createTempFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: I think this question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702537/is-createtempfile-thread-safe

Comment: According to javadoc this method may throw exception, therefore your code should be able to handle these exceptions. The error may occur for reasons other than duplicate name, for example disk failure etc.

EDIT: Also this method is static, therefore threadsafe (if you trust your JDK implementation)

Comment: @Andreas Bakurov Being static doesn't make a method thread safe. Are you perhaps thinking of static initializers?

Comment: @AndreasBakurov - Just because a method is marked `static` does **NOT** make it threadsafe.  In fact, marking something `static` is often a _cause_ of threading/concurrency bugs.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, call to static method from different threads will not cause problem with concurrent modification of File object , simply because there is no shared object. Also in parentheses I wrote "If you trust your JDK", it means that of course it is possible to have some bad Java singletons in static methods etc. But it is generally not the case in Oracle/Open Jdk. Therefore this call will be perfectly thread safe.

Comment: I reviewed the thread Ivan Nevostruev posted and it does answer my question. The method I have posted as-is will be safe in a multithreaded single JVM process environment. 

To make it safe in a multithreaded multi-JVM process environment (e.g. a clustered web app) you can use Chris Cooper's idea which involves passing a unique value in the prefix argument for the File.createTempFile method within each JVM process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer posted at the below URL answers my question. The method I posted is safe in a multithreaded single JVM process environment. To make it safe in a multithreaded multi-JVM process environment (e.g. a clustered web app) you can use Chris Cooper's idea which involves passing a unique value in the prefix argument for the File.createTempFile method within each JVM process.

[Is createTempFile thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702537/is-createtempfile-thread-safe)

Answer (score 2):

Just use the thread name and current time in millis to name the file.

Comment: So then does that mean my method as-is doesn't completely prevent the possibility of file name clashes in a multithreaded situation?

I want to avoid unnecessary unique file name generation or looping to ensure this works. If it's absolutely required I'll do it but I'm trying to keep it as clean as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You can supply a different prefix or suffix to the temporary files for this exact reason.
Assign a unique ID to each process starting up, and use that unique id as the prefix or suffix, multiple threads in the same VM will not clash, and now VMs will not clash either.

Comment: I'm more interested in knowing if the method I have is perfectly safe within a single multithreaded JVM process.